# Get Twitch channel ID from Python

Tags: python, oauth, token, twitch

It just says *{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"error getting authorization token"}*, don't know why as I can write on chat with my token. 
Here's the code:

```
url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channel"
channel_id = urllib.request.Request(url)
channel_id.add_header("Client-ID", CLIENT_ID)

#MY_OAUTH defined as MY_OAUTH = "oauth:123blablabla"
channel_id.add_header("Authorization: OAuth", MY_OAUTH")

response = urllib.request.urlopen(channel_id)
tmpJSON = json.loads(response.read())
```

**EDIT**: Here's the Pastebin of get_channel_id function: https://pastebin.com/Jm0EuWk9

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `Authorization` header is ill-formed. Supposing that `MY_OAUTH` as your access token, I believe you meant to write :

```
channel_id.add_header("Authorization", "OAuth " + MY_OAUTH)
```

Indeed, the [Twitch-API authentication documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/authentication/) recommends performing the following request when passing the access token in the HTTP header:

```
curl -H "Authorization: OAuth [access token]" https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/
```

As you can see, the header needs to be set as `Authorization: OAuth [access token]`, instead of `Authorization: OAuth: [access token]`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Anyway, I tried fixing my error but I obtain _urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized_ , that's weird becaure I am using the same OAuth when connecting to chat.
EDIT: even with a fresh new token, Maybe I should truncate token and set is without "oauth:" at the beginning?

Comment: Indeed, your token string should not include any additional character than the token itself, and must be of the form `pk2bh6y1vi8mrn7l67bp9i6dpg2wnk`. Have you tried removing the facing "oauth:" then ? And are you sure that it is the access token you are passing ?

Comment: Yes I fixed that yesterday. For some reason I am not able to get channel id: JSON returned from server is way different from what it should be. Acording o API's, should have "channel_id" field. With same parameters, using curl, JSON string is correct.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, are you still getting a `401 Unauthorized` error, or does the server return data now ? If so, can you provide more information on the difference between what you are getting and [what it should be](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#get-channel) ?

Comment: Now I'm only getting 401 Unauthorized error at _response = urllib.request.urlopen(channel_id)_